# Using UIToolbar : custom transparency, remove blur, keep translucent behavior

Tags: ios, ios7, uitoolbar

I'm using a toolbar in my iOS 7 app, and would like it to be of color blue, with transparency 0.85. When I set the color blue, the toolbar then appears greyish, and apply the blur effect on everything that's behind.
What I want is :

- no blur
- color blue with alpha 0.85
- keep the behavior of a translucent toolbar (for exemple, if you use a table view and a toolbar in a storyboard, the tableview will automatically have a bottom inset set to the toolbar size when the toolbar is shown)

Of course, I can set all my insets programmatically, but I wonder if it's possible to keep the automatic inset function without the blur.

Thanks in advance.